# Does Core Graphics provide a way to calculate the area of CGPath?

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics, metal

As the title says, I'm looking to calculate the area of a simple convex polygon contained in a normalized CGPath.

I was thinking of trying to implement the method described in the following Math answer:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/492503/4312

Before, starting I figured there must be something already doing this in either Core Graphics or Metal.

I'm not *that* familiar with graphics so any pointers are much appreciated!

Comment: If you convert the `CGPath` to a `VNContour`, then you can use `calculateArea(_:for:orientedArea:)`

Comment: "I figured there must be something already doing this in either Core Graphics or Metal." I'm curious why you would assume that. CG and Metal and drawing frameworks. What common drawing problem requires this calculation? (If there is a common drawing operation that needs this, it's worth opening a Feedback to request it.) Typically the CG way to achieve this is to draw it into a bitmap context with a fill and count the pixels. For an example of a similar problem (clipping a CGRect to an arbitrary path), see https://robnapier.net/clipping-cgrect-cgpath.

Comment: Can't believe I missed `calculateArea` thanks @Jeshua

Comment: @RobNapier Metal is not just a drawing framework, it is also a hardware accelerated computation framework.

Answer (score 0):

For convex polygonal path with counterclockwise winding and no self intersections:

```
import SpriteKit

let area = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFrom: cgPath).area * pow(150, 2)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skphysicsbody/1520034-area/